# Deserializing JObject that has no property name

Tags: c#, json.net

I want to be able to print the type, name and the sub entries, but I'm at a a loss as to how. Can I access specific positions of an array instead of naming the property I want?

The main property has entry properties, like mainProperty.entries, and I can pull the strings out using a foreach. But when the "entries" has properties that don't have a name, I have no idea how to access them.

I know that the "Entry text here" are JValues, and that the others are JObjects.

The entry without objects can be accessed through mainProperty.entries.
Since the other type doesn't have a name, I don't know how to access the type, name and "sub" entries. (mainProperty.JObject.type)

```
{
    "mainProperty": [
        {
            "entries": [
                "Entry text here",
                {
                    "type": "entries",
                    "name": "Entry of entry",
                    "entries": [
                        "Entry text here"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "entries",
                    "name": "Entry of entry",
                    "entries": [
                        "Entry text here"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

```
{
    "mainProperty": [
        {
            "entries": [
                "Entry text here",
                "Second line of text"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

```
foreach (var entry in mainProperty.entries)
{
         debugOutput(entry.GetType().ToString());
         //debugOutput("\t" + (string)entry);

}
```

The output should be:

*First example:*

```
Entry text here 
**Entry of entry** Entry text here 
**Entry of entry** Entry text here
```

*Second example:*

```
Entry text here
Second line of text
```

Comment: It's quite unclear what you are trying to get from your description. Can you show your desired output?

Comment: MainProperty have 2 Properties named entries? https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-4 _"The names within an object SHOULD be unique"_

Comment: Use the [edit]  button

Comment: _"
   An object whose names are all unique is interoperable in the sense
   that all software implementations receiving that object will agree on
   the name-value mappings.  When the names within an object are not
   unique, the behavior of software that receives such an object is
   unpredictable.  Many implementations report the last name/value pair
   only.  Other implementations report an error or fail to parse the
   object, and some implementations report all of the name/value pairs,
   including duplicates."_

Comment: This JSON is invalid. Copy/paste it in [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: Here's a clue, `entries` is an **array**, not an object. [this](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm) might be useful to you

Comment: That might be useful, thank you. If I get the length of the entries array, I'll be able to grab those properties I mentioned :)

Comment: first check entries has index or not then access them easily if entries has index loop through it if not then access them directly using dot operator still confusing then check whether index is string or int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your JSON, `entries` is an array of mixed types, where the values can either be strings or objects.  If they are objects, each child object has an `entries` property whose value is also an array.  In your examples it seems that this inner array will always contain strings, but it looks like it could actually be a fully recursive structure, where sub-entries can contain sub-sub-entries and so on.  If that is so, you would need a recursive method to dump out the entries.  Something like this could work:

```
public static void DumpEntries(JObject obj, string indent = "")
{
    JArray entries = (JArray)obj["entries"];
    if (entries != null)
    {
        foreach (JToken entry in entries)
        {
            if (entry.Type == JTokenType.String)
            {
                debugOutput(indent + entry.ToString());
            }
            else if (entry.Type == JTokenType.Object && (string)entry["type"] == "entries")
            {
                debugOutput(indent + "**" + (string)entry["name"] + "**");
                DumpEntries((JObject)entry, indent + "  ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it with your JSON like this:

```
var root = JObject.Parse(json);
foreach (JObject obj in (JArray)root["mainProperty"])
{
    DumpEntries(obj);
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MjRNGn

In answer to your original question,

> *Can I access specific positions of an array instead of naming the property I want?*

Yes, you absolutely can do this.

For example, if you wanted to get the first sub-entry of the third entry, you could do this:

```
var root = JObject.Parse(json);
var sub = root["mainProperty"][0]["entries"][2]["entries"][0];
debugOutput((string)sub);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/sMyMxH

Answer (score 0):

If you modify your JSON data like this:

```
var response = {
    "mainProperty": [{
        "entries": [{
                "type": "entries",
                "name": "Entry of entry",
                "entries": [
                    "Entry text here"
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "entries",
                "name": "Entry of entry",
                "entries": [
                    "Entry text here"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

You must create Response object but first, you need add NewtonSoft.Json to your project from NuGet. After add this library to your project you need to create Response object like this:

```
public class Entry
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<string> entries { get; set; }
}

public class MainProperty
{
    public List<Entry> entries { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<MainProperty> mainProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Than you can access your data:

```
var _res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response.ToString());

foreach(var item in _res.mainProperty.entries.entries)
{
     debugOutput(item);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the JSON scheme will not be modified. There's just to many files and entries for it to be viable.